# nth-of-type and nth-child in css not working properply

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want apply green color for the first nth child flag

```
<div id="axis">
     <div class="super"></div>
     <div class="flag">flag 1</div><!-- I want this text to be green-->
     <div class="super"></div>
     <div class="flag">flag 2</div>
     <div class="super"></div>
     <div class="flag">flag3</div>
     <div class="super"></div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
#axis{
    color:red;
}

#axis .flag:nth-of-type(1){
    color:green;  
}

#axis .flag:nth-child(1){
    color:green;
}
```

I tried in both scenario but not working...

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4pnh246q/1/)

Comment: The index number is `2`. so try using `2` instead of `1`.

Comment: `nt-child` and `nt-of-type` doesn't select according to class or ID.

Comment: Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/4pnh246q/2/ or http://jsfiddle.net/4pnh246q/3/

Comment: @MaryMelody - your answer is static

Comment: @web-tiki - I understood then what is the solution for my answer

Comment: `nth-of-type` works with only element selector.. it won't search for class

Comment: Since you have tagged jQuery, you could achieve that by [`:first` selector](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/): `$("#axis").find(".flag:first");`

Comment: @HashemQolami - I am looking for css

Comment: @JqueryKing So why did you tagged jQuery?

Comment: Jquery users also know css that why i am tagged jquery

Comment: What about `#axis .flag:nth-of-type(2)`? http://jsfiddle.net/4pnh246q/4/

Comment: If it's not about jQuery or you're not interested in a jQuery answer, don't tag it jQuery. Period.

Comment: @BradLarson - My timed suspension ends. But my reputation not recalculated again why. Please I want to continue in stackoverflow. Please check and do needful and kindly give me a reputation again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way  [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4pnh246q/16/)

```
<ul id="axis">
    <li class="flag">flag 1</li>
    <li class="flag">flag 2</li>
    <li class="flag">flag3</li>
</ul>

.flag {
    list-style:none;
    color:red;
}


.flag:nth-of-type(1) {

    color:green;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to acheive this is

```
<div id="axis">
    <div class="super"></div>
    <div class="flag">flag 1</div><!-- I want this text to be green-->
    <div class="super"></div>
    <div class="flag">flag 2</div>
    <div class="super"></div>
    <div class="flag">flag3</div>
    <div class="super"></div>
</div>
```

In CSS it will be

```
#axis > div:nth-child(2) {
    color: green;
}
```

### Another way:

Apply a common CSS:

```
.flag {
   /* first .flag element styles here */
   /* though these styles are applied to all .flag elements, in later step they get overridden. */
}

.flag + .flag{
    /* override above styles */
    /* Applies css to all the .flag elements except the first one */
}
```

Comment: your answer is static. Suppose nth-child(2) class is super means it also apply green it not the scenario

Comment: @JqueryKing Since, this post was closed..  I added my answer as "Another way" in this post. Abhijeet, I hope you are not offended.

Comment: @Mr_Green Not at all, I learned something so why should I be offended.

Comment: @Mr_Green - However, your way doesn't work. You want the general sibling combinator `~`, not the adjacent sibling combinator `+`.

Comment: @Alohci both works same. because I am not using `:first-child` or and other specific pseudo class here.